# How to delete a group permanently?

Tags: powershell, office365

I have been trying to permanently delete a group from 0365 via PowerShell by using AppRegistration but I keep getting Insufficient Permissions.

I can delete the group with `Remove-PnPMicrosoft365Group` or `Remove-MgGroup` and after these commands, the group is moved to deleted items. But when I try to delete the deleted group permanently, I always get insufficient permissions. Both `Remove-MgDirectoryDeletedItem` and `Remove-PnPDeletedMicrosoft365Group` did not work for me:

[image: InsufficientPermission]

I also tried directly from Graph explorer but I received the same error although I consented all possible permissions.

By the way, I can permanently delete the deleted group from Azure Portal.

Any ideas ?

Thx

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anybody needs help for such requirement, there are two options:

- Give the app registration "Company Admin (Global Admin as of today)" as described here : https://konstantinvlasenko.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/microsoft-graph-api-insufficient-privileges-to-delete-a-group/
  But this option will not work later than July 2023 because Microsoft is deprecating MSOL.
- App Registration usage is not possible for permanently deleting directory objects : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
  So you will need to use MSGraph with user authentication.

Just fyi, when you try to permanently delete O365 group from Graph Explorer, you will need to consent to Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Regards,